# Why is the order of returning the sefer-torah different on shabbos than on weekday?

Tags: shabbat, torah-service, nusach-ashkenaz, chol-weekday

Why on shabbos is ashrai said before returning the sefer-torah and on weekday (nusach ashkenaz) afterwards. This cannot have to do with kaddish tiskabel since this is also done on rosh chodesh where kaddish tiskabel has already been said like on shabbos.

Answer (score 10):

[Aishel Avraham (Buchach) Orach Chaim 149](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36229&st=&pgnum=35) says that the reason that Minhag Ashkenaz returns the Sefer Torah before Ashrei on the weekdays was since there are some people that take off their Tefilin while they are saying
 'יהי רצון שלא נבוש' which is in Uvo L'Tziyon and it is improper to remove Tefilin in front of the Sefer Torah therefore they return the Sefer Torah prior to Ashrei. However on Shabbos when people do not wear Tefilin there is no such issue.

Comment: I would add that minhag of nusach sefard is to always return the Torah after ashrei perhaps because they follow Ari to leave tefillin on until after first half of aleinu (mishna berurah 25:55)

Comment: This would not explain chol hamoed where one has already taken off his tfillin (except first day pesach chol hamoed).

Comment: This also does not explain why it is preferable to say ashrai before returning the sefer like on shabbos.

Comment: @preferred, I suspect (although without a source) that taking off the Tefillin that early started later.

Comment: @Gershon Gold So the answer is really this. One should pray as much as one can while the sefer is 'open'. That is why we put the sefer back as late as possible like on shabbos just before musaph. It is only if we have a reason not to like in the weekdays that we put the sefer back earlier.

Comment: On rosh hashono therefore it would be correct to blow shofar while the sefer is in the open. Not everyone does this especially those who make a break then. On purim some do keep the sefer in the open while reading the megilla see tosfos.