# Reciting Psalm 145 three times a day without minyan

Tags: shabbat, tehilim-psalms, shacharis-morning-prayer

As it is commonly known, [Berakhot 4b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=4b&format=pdf) praises the person, who says [Psalm 145](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e5.htm) three times a day. We do it by reciting *Ashrei* in the morning as a part of *Pesukei dezimrah* ([Orach Chayim 51:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%96), [Mishneh Torah Tefilah 7:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920169/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Seven.htm)) and before *minchah* ([Orach Chayim 234:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%90), [Mishneh Torah Tefilah 7:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920169/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Seven.htm)). There is a second recital of *Ashrei* ([Mishneh Torah Tefilah 7:17](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920169/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Seven.htm)) in the weekday morning prayer before *Uva leTziyon.* On Monday and Thursday this is after the Torah is brought back to the ark,* but on Shabbat it is said while the scroll is still outside. Last Shabbat I had a terrible cold and I couldn't pray with a *minyan.* As *Ashrei* might seem to be a part of the Torah reading, I was wondering if I had to say it between the morning prayer and the *mussaf,* or there was another designated place for its recital.

<sup>* *Sefardim* do it after *Ashrei*</sup>

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37694/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76279/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20376/15256

Comment: Not everyone has that Girsa in the Gemara. The Geonim write that saying three times in the service is just to make sure everyone says it at least once so they all get olam haba

Comment: What else would you be doing between Shacharit and Musaf? You aren't allowed to say the Amida twice back to back. That's why we put Ashrei before Neilah. Seemingly this would be the same. Frankly I don't know where else you'd want to put it.

Comment: It's not part of the Torah reading.  It's an intro to musaf, same as the intro to mincha.

Comment: @DoubleAA If you have a source for your second comment that might be an answer!

Comment: @Heshy Then why don't we switch the order and place it right before the _musaf?_

Comment: Ashrei really belongs to musaf.  There's a side point that we want to keep the sefer Torah out as long as possible, so we put it back after ashrei.  But (according to that answer) on weekdays we can't because of tefillin.  (I don't find that answer so convincing because of tisha beav and those who don't wear tefillin on chol hamoed, but ok.). The point remains that the ashrei doesn't really have to do with the Torah reading.  I know of one minyan that has a break before musaf.  They skip ashrei and put back the sefer Torah, then break, then ashrei kaddish musaf.

Comment: Ashrei has an interesting "quirk" in that it is also used to introduce *Selichot*. While that doesn't answer your Q, here, it may have some relationship to what's behind saying it altogether and it's connection to davening.

Comment: @DanF While I like your idea, Germans do not say _Ashrei_ before _Selichot_

Comment: @DanF I wouldn't call it a quirk of Ashrei exactly, it's more that it's used to introduce a tefilah.  Think about it - _every single_ tefilah of the year except Maariv and Y"K Mincha has Ashrei before it.  Selichot are structured as a pseudo-tefilah.  If anything it's an interesting quirk of Selichot.

Comment: @Heshy - My poor phrasing. I meant to say that there's something special about Ashrei itself that it is chosen to introduce Selichot. After all, there are over 145 other Tehillim to choose from.

Comment: I have to hunt a beurei hatefilah.com article that I saw a while ago that discusses Ashrei. I think the central point was that it was meant as a prayer for the individual to be said as meditation prior to tefillah (or, perhaps, it was just *mincha*)? Focus was on th ebeginning verse that talks about praising those that "sit in your house" - meaning the *bet k'nesset*. The Gemarrah, BTW, seems to refer to *Tehilla L'David* which seems to indicate that adding the verse "Ashrei" might not have been common or known at that time and could be a much later addition.

Comment: @DanF I see what you mean, but Selichot are not really "special" in this respect.  Ashrei is chosen to introduce Selichot because Selichot are trying to copy tefilah.  There are two very good questions here, (1) why are they trying to copy tefilah and (2) why is Ashrei chosen for tefilah in general.  But I don't think trying to correlate (1) and (2) is that illuminating.